# Bundler doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle, bundler

Excuse my Rails noobitude.

After running bundle install, all my gems install correctly.

When I run bundle update, it outputs a list of my installed gems and tells me "Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed."

I try 'bundle show rake' and the output is exactly the same. When I'm trying to rake db:migrate with bundle exec, the output is exactly the same the the db migration doesn't even happen.

Do I have something wrong with my bundler or something?

I am so confused.

```
$ bundle update rake
"BundlingUsing rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.5) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.5) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.3) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.14) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.29) 
Using actionpack (3.0.5) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.2) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.2.19) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.5) 
Using arel (2.0.10) 
Using activerecord (3.0.5) 
Using activeresource (3.0.5) 
Using bundler (1.0.15) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.5) 
Using rails (3.0.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.4) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense :( Why are you running `bundle update`? What is the first output of `rake db:migrate` and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: To note: `bundle update rake` will update the bundle's version of rake to the highest that can be supported by the restrictions enforced by the other gems that you're using. You're using Rails 3.0.5 and so the rake version is going to be 0.8.7 based on the dep in `railties 3.0.5`. To use 0.9.2, upgrade to Rails 3.0.9.

Comment: Okay, but what I mean is every input outputs the same thing and nothing changes. Bundle exec db:migrate should perform the database migration, yes? But it doesn't do anything, it just outputs the same thing I pasted up there and doesn't perform the db migration. Why?

Comment: I know that bundle update performs updating gems, sorry that was poorly written.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and found my solution here: [Bundler ignores groups in rails apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314512/bundler-ignores-groups-in-rails-apps?rq=1)

Summary:
Do the following:

```
rm .bundle/config
bundle install
```